$ \inf_{k \geq n'} x_k \leq \sup_{k \geq n} x_k \text{ for all } n' \in \mathbb{N}.$
Trying to proof something about the limit superior and if I have the claim below, I am done. But im not sure the claim and my proof of it is correct.
Let $(x_n)$ be some sequence, $\sup_{k\ge n} x_k$ is the supremum of the tail with starting index $n$.
Claim: For a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$, the specific value $\sup_{k \geq n} x_k$ is an upper bound for the sequence of infima $(\inf_{k \geq n'} x_k)$, for all $n' \in \mathbb{N}$. Equivalently $
\inf_{k \geq n'} x_k \leq \sup_{k \geq n} x_k \text{ for all } n' \in \mathbb{N}.$
Proof. Since the seqence of supremums is non-increasing, it follows that $\sup_{k\ge n} x_k$ is an upper-bound of $(\sup_{k\ge n'} x_k)_{n' \ge n}$. Furthermore, since $\sup_{k\ge k'} x_k \ge \inf_{k\ge k'} x_k$ holds for any $k'$, we further have that $\sup_{k\ge n} x_k$ is an upper-bound of $(\inf_{k\ge n'} x_k)_{n' \ge n}$. Now if $n'<n$, then $\inf_{k\ge n'} x_k \le  x_n \le \sup_{k\ge n} x_k$ and thus the desired claimn follows.

First of all, I will proof the next proposition:
Proposition: If two noempty sets $A$ and $B$ of real numbers have $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ then $\inf{A} \leq \sup{B}$.
Proof: By hypothesis $A \cap B \neq \emptyset$ so there exists $x \in A \cap B$. By definition of $\inf{A}$ we have that $\inf{A}$ is a lower-bound of $A$ so $\inf{A} \leq x$. Reasoning analogous for upper-bound give us that $x \leq \sup{B}$.
We conclude $\inf{A} \leq \sup{B}$. $□$
Turning back to the original problem, we always have that the subsequences $(x_{k})_{k \geq n}$ and $(x_{k})_{k \geq n'}$ have non-empty intersection (all the $x_{k}$ for all $k \geq \max\{n,n'\}$) so by the previous proposition we have that $\inf_{k \geq n'}x_{k} \leq \sup_{k \geq n}x_{k}$ for all $n,n' \in \mathbb{N}$.
